# How to display vocabulary terms and their descriptions with their tagged content in a view?

Tags: 7, views

Say I have two terms in a vocabulary, and I want to display their titles and descriptions, along with a list of nodes which have been tagged. Here's an example:

Page Title: Services

```
Term Name: Medical
Term Description: We're the best doctors in town!
Content tagged with term: Brain Surgery, Leg Amputation

Term Name: Business
Term Description: We'll make you rich!
Content tagged with term: Accounting, Management, Bookkeeping, Strategy
```

How could I accomplish this using Views in Drupal 7?

I've tried creating a term view, adding the term name and term description fields, enabling a relationship for 'Content with Term', adding a field for 'Content: Title', and grouping by Term name with 'Use rendered output to group rows' disabled, but I still get a ton of duplicates.

Any way to resolve this?

### Debunked Methods:

**Use aggregation!** - Nope, this results in something like this (not what we're after here):

```
Term Name: Medical
Term Description: We're the best doctors in town!
Content tagged with term: Brain Surgery

Term Name: Medical
Term Description: We're the best doctors in town!
Content tagged with term: Leg Amputation
```

**Use the Views Distinct module!** - Nope, nothing here seems to work either.

## Update

Jimmy's Answer works well for my situation. Alternatively, I also believe that creating a custom display for your taxonomy and developing a field that displays related content based on TID could circumvent your need for views at all. If you're desperate and less paranoid about logic-less templates, you could do that heavy lifting in your theme (don't do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using some other contrib modules with views, [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) can be the best solution.

### Create content views

First, create a content views to list the content title which contains the taxonomy term, add field ***Content: Title*** and add the taxonomy term field as contextual filter. (e.g. ***Content: Tags*** (field_tags) in screenshot)

> ***Use aggregation*** is to remove the duplicated content because same term can be attached on one content more then once.

[image: content views]

### Create taxonomy term views

Second, create a taxonomy term views to list the ***Taxonomy term: Name*** and ***Taxonomy term: Term description*** under a vocabulary, which is similar to the one you have created.

> BUT, you **don't need** to add the relationship ***Content with Term*** neither the field ***Content: Title***

[image: taxonomy term views]

Field ***Taxonomy term: Term ID*** is used as contextual argument, so exclude it from display.

[image: Taxonomy term: Term ID]

### Attach views field view

Add a views field, select the taxonomy term view you created and place `[!tid]` as the argument of Contextual filters.

[image: views field]

### Result

All required data is ready now, you may need to override the views template files for modifying the output.

[image: Example result]

### Performance

> This method involves multiple views, the performance may become an issue if there are many contents and terms. You should enable the time-based cache on the content views.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I like this answer. It's hard for me to believe that after 5 years of Drupal-ing I've never used this module!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has already answer. You can follow following answer where it has been prepared using Views module.

[Displaying Drupal taxonomy term desciption in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422705/displaying-drupal-taxonomy-term-desciption-in-node)

Comment: This post doesn't accomplish the same thing. We need to display all terms of a vocabulary with their descriptions along with all the content that has been tagged with those terms (grouped).