# Replacement pattern in view field template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a body field view template:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * This template is used to print a single field in a view.
 *
 * It is not actually used in default Views, as this is registered as a theme
 * function which has better performance. For single overrides, the template is
 * perfectly okay.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $view: The view object
 * - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
 * - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
 * - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
 *
 * When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
 * $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}
 *
 * The above will guarantee that you'll always get the correct data,
 * regardless of any changes in the aliasing that might happen if
 * the view is modified.
 */
?>
<?php print $output; ?>
```

What I want is:

```
if nid == 1
print $output =  view_embed_view('my custom view')
else
print $output;
```

How can we do this?

**Note**: I'm already using the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module, but can't figure out as how to apply this condition of nid.

Comment: I don't understand your question....

Comment: Actually I want to embed view on basis of node id. So if node id == 1 or something else, I will replace body field content with some other view.

Comment: [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) may help.

Comment: I'm already using this module, but can't figure out as how to apply this condition of nid?

Comment: You can take a look my [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209232/how-can-i-display-vocabulary-terms-and-their-descriptions-with-their-tagged-cont/209250#209250) in other post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view template file of body field, write this code;

```
$nid = $row->nid;
$body = $row->body;
if($nid == 1):
  $view = views_get_view('VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME');
  $view->set_display('DISPLAY_ID');
  $new_view = $view->preview('DISPLAY_ID');
  print render($new_view);
else :
  print $body;
endif;
```